# TSQL - Add WW to YYYYWW (Similar to MOD function)

Tags: t-sql

I have been storing data as year and week number in one of our columns, i.e., Last year week 40 was recorded as:

> 201840 (YYYYWW)

I want to add 20 weeks to above number, simple addition would be like 201840 + 20 = 201860, however a year has 52 weeks, so it should be more like:

> 201908

I have tried this with no luck:
`select (201840+20) % 52` = the result is 48
And have tried the DATE function with no luck either `DATE (LEFT(201840, 4),1 , 1  + (RIGHT(201840, 2)* 7 + 20`

Is there something like a mod function that will give the desired result of 201908?

Comment: Week numbers are not as simple as they appear to be at first glance. There are rules you must be following: For instance - If January 1st is a Tuesday, is the first week of the year January 1st through January 6th (That Tuesday to the first Sunday), or is the first week of the year starts on Monday, January 7th? Also, what if the week itself starts on Sunday and not on Monday? It also reflect on what happens if December 31st is a Wednesday - does Thursday, Friady Saturday and Sunday belong to the next year or the current? A calendar table would help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are generally faster than string functions:

```
((201840 / 100)  
+ iif((201840 % 100 + 20 < 52), 0, 1)) * 100 
+ ((201840 % 100 + 20) % 52)
```

You can test different values by using variables as opposed to hard-coding the date and increment value.

```
DECLARE @date INT = 201840, @increment INT = 20

SELECT 
((@date / 100) 
+ iif((@date % 100 + @increment < 52), 0, 1)) * 100 
+ ((@date % 100 + @increment) % 52)
```

Comment: Whats  the use of `(@date / 1000 * 10)` , I get the same result with the below:  
DECLARE @date INT = 201840, @increment INT = 20  SELECT  
    ((@date / 100)  
    + iif((@date % 100 + @increment < 52), 0, 1)) * 100  
    + ((@date % 100 + @increment) % 52)

Comment: Absolutely. Keep up the perceptiveness :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lengthy script to solve this, but would appreciate if anyone can assist in optimizing this nested script:

> CONCAT(
>   DATEPART(YEAR,(
>   DATEADD(WEEK,CAST(RIGHT(201840, 2)+20 AS INT),
>   DATEADD(YEAR,CAST(LEFT(201840, 4) AS INT) - 1900,0 ))))
>   ,RIGHT(
>   CONCAT('00', 
>   DATEPART(WEEK,(DATEADD(WEEK,CAST(RIGHT(201840, 2)+20 AS INT), DATEADD(YEAR,CAST(LEFT(201840, 4) AS INT) - 1900,0 ))))) 
>   , 2)
>   )`